# Moving of 5 units on a curve

Tags: parametric, curves, parametrization, arc-length

If I am at a point (0, 0, 3) and a move of 5 units in the positive direction of $t$ on a curve definite by 
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= 3\sin(t) \\
y &= 4t \\
z &= 3\cos(t)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Where am I ?

I am not sure how to start this problem. What does $5$ units in the positive direction* of t means ? It's probably not that I have to do $t+5$. Maybe I need to set the parametric equation and find the length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a circular helix; the lenght $s$ of an arc is easily calculated and equal to $s=t\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5t$.

When$(x,y,z)=(0,0,3)=(3\sin t,4t, \cos t)$ which is compatible with the value $t=0$.

When $s=5$ this corresponds to $5=5t$ so to the value $t=1$ of the parameter.

Hence the corresponding point is $(x,y,z)=(3\sin 1,4, 3\cos 1)$ where $1$ is one radian, of course.

We have $x\approx 3\cdot 0,841470=2,52441$; $y=4$; $z\approx 3\cdot0,540302=1,620906$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I understand that we are moving of units so we can assume that the given point is the start of the curve, so when we using equation, it is in function of this start. So, looking 5 units further is like going at the point where the length is 5 (in relation of the starting point). I am not sure how you managed to find the length $s$. Did you use the equation 
$$ L = \int_0^{2\pi} \| \mathbf{\vec{r}} \| dt $$.

Comment: The circular helix occurs on the cylinder  of base $x^2+z^2= 3^2$ in the plane XOZ. Its arc grows in length when $y$ increases in the positive direction proportional to 4. This arc is deduced from the standard differential formula in dimension three $(ds)^2= (dx)^2+(dy)^2 +(dz)^2$  so $ds= \sqrt{9\sin^2 x+9\cos ^2 x+4^2}dt$ . Pardon for bad English (that could cause of a mathematical mistake in what I said).

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: You are welcome